# What are the fees for selling ETFs from a savings plan in Germany?

Tags: etf, fees, germany

When I create a savings plan for ETFs in Germany at a german bank, I collect securities, ETFs in this context, over time. After the end of my savings plan's duration, I do not exactly understand what happens.

Does a bank usually sell all securities from the savings plan after this savings plan duration or do I hold them automatically? 
Furthermore, where do I have to look of the fees for selling securities?

Price lists are clear about the costs of buying securities, for example 1,5% per volume for buys through a savings plan. But I do not know the right category for the selling of securities, especially collected through an ETF savings plan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on the exact terms of this specific "savings plan" offered by your bank. It is not a standardized product.

However, the ones I am familiar with (especially given that you cite a flat percentage fee) do not really have a "duration" at all. While the plan is active, you buy securities for a certain amount each month. You can deactivate and reactivate the plan and change the monthly amount at any time, as often as you want. The plan is really just a special way to *buy* those securities.

The securities accumulate in your account, they are not sold automatically. If you want to sell them, you have to do that via the normal stock exchange order interface, and it will incur fees in the same way any stock order does, which will depend on which stock exchange you choose.

These fees tend to be quite low, and in fact if your monthly investment is more than a few hundred Euros you would save money by buying the securities manually rather than through such a plan.